# Visual Studio 2017 Error - language feature 'nested-namespace-definition' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'

Tags: c++17

Using MS Visual studio I created a solution containing 2 projects called MainProject and CalcProject
MainProject is a console app that references CalcProject  and only contains main() in a .cpp file
CalProject is a library and contains a few header files with the following:

Nml.h contains the following:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include " Ftr.h"
#include " Mtr.h"

namespace CalcProject::measure

{
    class Mtr;
    class Ftr;

    class Nml
    {
    public:
          ...
```

Ftr.h contains the following:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include " Mtr.h"
#include " Nml.h"
namespace CalcProject::measure
{
    class Mtr;
    class Nml;

    class Ftr
    {
        ...
```

Mtr.h contains the following:

```
#include " Ftr.h"
#include " Nml.h"
namespace CalcProject::measure
{

   class Ftr;
   class Nml;

    class Mtr
    {
        ...
```

MainProject.cpp contains the following:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Ftr.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace CalcProject::measure;

int main()
{
```

When I build the solution I receive the following error
Error   C2429   language feature 'nested-namespace-definition' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17' MainProject
I tried to resolve this by specifying /std:c++17 in the C++ Language standard in the project properties but the error persists.

How can I fix this? Please advise on a possible solution. I am a beginner and this is my first C++ project using multiple header and cpp files to create a library.

Comment: Make sure you set `/std:c++17` for all configuration and all platforms in project properties.

Comment: That worked !... I had to change it for all platforms.Thank you